# How do I get the Magnolia empty webapp running with the Standard Templating Kit?

Tags: java, xml, maven, dependencies, magnolia

I'm having lots of trouble getting the Magnolia empty webapp project running, all related to Maven dependencies. It seems to be an extreme case of *If you give a mouse a cookie*, because every time I add a required dependency it throws an exception asking for another, and it's never enough.

I've been trying to follow [this guide](http://dev.magnolia-cms.com/~gjoseph/dont-build-magnolia-build-your-projects), which starts out using the Maven archetype command so it's not quite from scratch. The problem is that guide was written awhile back so the version numbers have changed a lot since then, and it seems the newest versions just aren't compatible with themselves.

Here's what my **acme-project-webapp/pom.xml** file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
        <artifactId>acme-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>acme-project-webapp</artifactId>
    <name>Acme Project: webapp</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>magnolia-repo</id>
            <name>Magnolia Repository</name>
            <url>https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-dms</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-fckeditor</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-module-mail</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
        <artifactId>magnolia-imaging-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <dependentWarExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</dependentWarExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I try to run the project, I get a host of exception messages. Here's what they say:

> The following exceptions were found while checking Magnolia modules dependencies (i.e. those in META-INF/magnolia/my-module.xml):
>   Module Magnolia JSP Templating Support Module (version 5.4.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.3/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia RSS Aggregator Module (version 2.4.0) is dependent on scheduler (version 2.2/*), but Magnolia Scheduler Module (version 2.1.1) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia RSS Aggregator Module (version 2.4.0) is dependent on mte (version 0.5/*), which was not found.
>
> Module Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.6.9) is dependent on adminInterface (version 4.5.8/*), but Magnolia Admin Interface Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia DMS Module (version 1.6.9) is dependent on fckEditor (version 4.5.8/*), but Magnolia FCKEditor Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia DAM Templating (version 2.1.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.4/* - optional), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Standard Templating Kit Module (version 2.9.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.3/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Standard Templating Kit Module (version 2.9.0) is dependent on adminInterface (version 5.2/*), but Magnolia Admin Interface Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Inplace Templating Module (version 2.4.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.4/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Public User Registration Module (version 2.4.3) is dependent on templating (version 5.3/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia 4.5 Migration Module (version 1.2.4) is dependent on adminInterface (version 4.5.10/*), but Magnolia Admin Interface Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Resources Module (version 2.4.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.4/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Module Forum (version 3.4.6) is dependent on adminInterface (version 5.0.2/*), but Magnolia Admin Interface Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Site Module (version 1.0.0) is dependent on templating (version 5.4/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.
>
> Module Magnolia Form Module (version 2.2.12) is dependent on templating (version 5.2.2/*), but Magnolia Templating Module (version 4.4.2) is currently installed.

At first I would get messages saying dependencies were not found (in addition to the version mismatches), and so whenever I saw those I would try adding in the missing dependencies one by one. But it's been a long rabbit hole I've been falling down.

Fundamentally I don't really care about all these nested dependencies that it seems to require; all I really want is to get this running with the Standard Templating Kit, and once that's in place, with the Jackrabbit Persistence Manager (so I can use MySQL). Why is this so hard to get running out of the box? How do I even get it running in the first place?

**EDIT:** Here's the parent POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.acme</groupId>
<artifactId>acme-project</artifactId>
<name>Acme Project (parent pom)</name>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
  <magnoliaVersion>5.4</magnoliaVersion>
  <javaVersion>1.6</javaVersion>
</properties>

<scm>
  <connection/>
  <developerConnection/>
  <url/>
</scm>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-project</artifactId>
      <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.ui</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-ui-project</artifactId>
      <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.magnolia.bundle</groupId>
      <artifactId>magnolia-bundle-parent</artifactId>
      <version>${magnoliaVersion}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- TEST -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${javaVersion}</source>
        <target>${javaVersion}</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>

  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>META-INF/magnolia/*</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>magnolia.public</id>
    <url>https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public</url>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
  <repository>
    <id>vaadin-addons</id>
    <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<modules>
  <module>acme-project-webapp</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

Comment: What is your Magnolia version, i.e. the version of the `magnolia-empty-webapp` artifact? It seems you have mixed the versions - `magnolia-empty-webapp` is older than the modules you've added as separate dependencies.

Comment: Magnolia Version 5.4

Comment: Share the parent `pom.xml` please.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after loading you pom.xml files into Eclips, I finally see the problem: you've added the `magnolia-module-dms` and `magnolia-module-fckeditor` dependencies, but these are for Magnolia 4.x, not for the 5.x line - and they dragged in obsolete versions of the concerned modules.

Remove these dependencies - you don't need them. The DMS module has been replaced with DAM module (you'll get it as a sub-dependency of the STK module), and the FCK Editor is no more used.

Answer (score 0):

For **Magnolia Version 5.4** please dependency into your **pom.xml** file in **theme** module

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-legacy-admininterface</artifactId>
  <version>5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Please see more at https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/AdminInterface+module

Regards,